# Psalm 2:6 "I have installed my king on Zion, my holy mountain."

Tags: psalms

Which Kings does Psalm 2:6 refer to?

"I have installed my king on Zion, my holy mountain."

Answer (score 1):

**Psalm 2:6 “I have installed my king on Zion, my holy mountain.”**

Psalm 2:6-7 (ASV)

**God speaks.**

> 6 "Yet I have set my king  Upon my holy hill of Zion."

**Jesus, the Messianic King speaks.**

> 7 "I will tell of the decree: Jehovah said unto me, Thou art my son;
>   This day have I begotten thee."

Mount Zion was a hill in Jerusalem where David was installed as king over all Israel. But  Jesus the Messianic King, will not sit on a throne in that city or elsewhere on earth.

**The throne is in Heaven.**

Revelation 11:15  (ASV)

> 15 "And the seventh angel sounded; and there followed **great voices in
>   heaven, and they said, The kingdom of the world is become the kingdom
>   of our Lord, and of his Christ: and he shall reign  for ever and
>   ever."**

Revelation 14:1-2  (ASV)

> 1 "And I saw, and behold, the Lamb standing on the mount Zion, and
>   with him a hundred and forty and four thousand, having his name, and
>   the name of his Father, written on their foreheads. 2 And I heard a
>   voice from heaven, as the voice of many waters, and as the voice of a
>   great thunder: and the voice which I heard was as the voice of harpers
>   harping with their harps:"